# Detecting log-ins with SENS

Tags: windows-services, sens

I have a .Net service that uses SENS to detect when a user logs on or off. I'm having two problems, though:

1. Even though the service seems to be
   starting automatically, if there is
   only one user on the computer and
   that user doesn't have a password
   (meaning windows will start right
   away), the log-in doesn't seem to be
   getting detected. Is it possible
   that the service is getting started
   too late? If so, what are my
   options?
2. I don't seem to have a way to detect windows switches users. In other words, if I log in with person A, I can detect that. If I then switch users (meaning person A doesn't log out) to person B, person B logs in and I detect that. But if I switch back to person A, no log-on has taken place, and I don't know that the switch took place. Is there a way, via SENS, to catch these events. I seem to only be able to catch Display locks/unlocks, logging on/off, when the screensaver starts/stops, and when the shell starts. Is it possible to do more with SENS, or perhaps to detect when the user is switched using these operations? Or perhaps by some other technique?

Comment: I've just found ISensLogon2, which has SessionDisconnect and SessionReconnect methods. I think these might accommodate switching users. I'll get that implemented, unless someone verifies that I'm wrong about that. I don't think it's going to help my start-up problem, though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ISensLogon2 gave me SessionDisconnect and SessionReconnect, which happen when the user is switched without logging off. I don't have a technical way to solve the second problem, so I'm just circumventing it.

Comment: Would you mind to share your code on how to suscribe or use this ISensLogon2 interface?

Comment: I used something called ManagedSENSE. It's a .Net library that you can use to subscribe to events. I don't think I did anything special with it.